# Как составить нестандартный delete запрос в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть такой SQL запрос

```
DELETE FROM tbl_um_keys WHERE user_id = 6 AND module_id IN (20, 21, 31);
```

Как этот запрос можно реализовать средствами `Yii2`

Comment: Есть еще у кого нибудь варианты

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Средствами ActiveRecord

```
YourModel::deleteAll(['user_id' => 6, 'module_id' => [20, 21, 31]]);
```

Либо средствами Connection

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
  ->delete('tbl_um_keys', ['user_id' => 6, 'module_id' => [20, 21, 31]])
  ->execute()
```

Answer (score -2):

Как-то так похоже

```
  $records=tbl_um_keys::find()->where(['user_id'=>6])->andWhere(['in','module_id',[20,21,31]])->all();
  $records->delete();
```

Comment: Не получается пишет `Call to a member function delete() on a non-object`